# LINQ-to-MongoDB - Return list only when values between 2 columns match

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, c#-4.0, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a MongoDB collection.  Here's a grid (excel) view of the source data.
[image: Source list]

I only want to return a list if the values from "fstick" column matches the values from "sedol" column in the same collection.  In the end, I want this:
[image: Result list]

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var list1 = collection.AsQueryable();
var list2 = collection.AsQueryable();
var docs = list1.Where(c => list2.Any(a => a.Sedol == c.FSTicker));
```

And this:

```
var docs = collection.AsQueryable()
        .Where(c => c.FSTicker.Contains(c.Sedol));
```

Each time, I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Unsupported filter: {document}{fstick}.Contains({document}{sedol}).
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateWhere(WhereExpression node)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslatePipeline(PipelineExpression node)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Translate(Expression expression)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Execute(Expression expression)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2.GetEnumerator()
```

Just in case, here's my class:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Datapull
{
    [BsonElement("fstick")]
    public string FSTicker { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("sedol")]
    public string Sedol { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("exchange")]
    public string Exchange { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("localtick")]
    public string LocalTicker { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("compname")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

What should I change to LINQ query to make this work?

**Additional Info:**

- MongoDB version:  3.0.4
- C# driver:  2.2.4
- Json document dump (exported from MongoChef & modified)

  ```
  [{
          "fstick" : "25881xx",
          "exchange" : "OTC",
          "localtick" : "MSFT",
          "sedol" : "25881xx",
          "compname" : "Microsoft Corporation",
          "currency" : "USD",
          "closedate" : "2016-07-11"
      }, {
          "fstick" : "2046xxx",
          "exchange" : "NASDQ",
          "localtick" : "AAPL",
          "sedol" : "2046xxx",
          "compname" : "Apple Inc.",
          "currency" : "USD",
          "closedate" : "2016-07-11"
      }, {
          "fstick" : "BCBHZxx",
          "exchange" : "NASDQ",
          "localtick" : "BBRY",
          "sedol" : "BCBHZxx",
          "compname" : "BlackBerry Limited",
          "currency" : "USD",
          "closedate" : "2016-07-11"
      }, {
          "fstick" : "BB-CA",
          "exchange" : "TSE",
          "localtick" : "BB",
          "sedol" : "BCBHZ3x",
          "compname" : "BlackBerry Limited",
          "currency" : "CAD",
          "closedate" : "2016-07-11"
      }
  ]
  ```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%22Unsupported+filter%22

Comment: What is the result that you expect?

Comment: are you looking for substring or exact value comparison?

Comment: Exact value comparison.

Comment: I've just updated the question to show more details.

Comment: The way you describe it, it seems to be as simple as `list1.Where(c => c.Sedol == c.FSTicker)`. Also, you mention *a MongoDB collection* (i.e. *one*). And then you do something with `list1` and `list2`. I must be missing something.

Comment: @GertArnold this is nosql documet sir....

Comment: tryed      var docs = collection.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(c => c.FSTicker.Equals(c.Sedol)); ?

Comment: @CiroCorvino that did it.  That was so easy.  Would you submit an official answer?  I'd like to award the bounty.  Thank you.

Comment: hey @inquisitive_one you have made a little joke :)  and I admit to have been fooled eheheheh :DD  God Bless You  :DDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @Ciro Corvino for the following answer:

```
var docs = collection.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.FSTicker.Equals(c.Sedol));
```

Answer (score 5):

As this explores a problem when we need compare two fields from same document,
please find snippet which is using Aggregation framework.

the `Datapull` class got extra field for that:

```
public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
```

C# Aggregation Framework snippet below

```
        var data = collection.Aggregate();
        var a1 =
            data.Project(
                x =>
                    new 
                    {
                        FSTicker = x.FSTicker,
                        Sedol = x.Sedol,
                        Company = x.Company,
                        Exchange = x.Exchange,
                        LocalTicker = x.LocalTicker,
                        IsTrue = (x.Sedol == x.FSTicker)
                    });
        var a2 = a1.Match(x => x.IsTrue);

        var result = a2.ToList();
```

**EDIT**

problem here is based on fact, that mongo itself doesn't have method to compare fields on same documents, which for peoples coming from SQL world it is something natural.

Mongo have a `$where` clause - it is a javascript injection and we can pass such a snippet to operate on each returned document from our dataSet, but linq query is not translated to use this.

There is a JIRA ticket here: [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1701)

***EDIT 2***

Please download example from repo - maybe something is missing there
Below screen shot of working solution

Git repo [here](https://github.com/profesor79/SOSolver/blob/master/SoQuestionsSolver/SoQuestionsSolver/CompareOnSameDocumentFieldsSteps.cs)

[image: results]

Any comments welcome!

Comment: would you provide more details on your answer?

Comment: Odd!  I tried your suggestion and I'm getting no results.

Comment: Could you tell me what driver version is in use?

Comment: Could you add your document dump?

Comment: Are you referring to mongodump?

Comment: no, apologies -need to see the document in json whatever client you use to connect to mongo - I will import it and validate code.

Comment: updated the question with the details that you asked for.

Comment: how do I see your code in the repo? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @profesor79 I removed my answer but confirm how said about yours.. inquisitive_one it is a great joker eheheh :)

Comment: @profesor79 you  should only post image in your answer if it's necessary. You should prioritize the copy/past option as it is more readable. Also you don't need to add *Any comments welcome!* to your answers (You've been doing this for a while now).